# How to fix overflow in enumarate item?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have to enumerate an article like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}

    \item Core distance: A point P is a core point if it has at least minimum points within its \(\epsilon\)-neighborhood \(N_ \epsilon \)(p) (including the point P) 

\begin{equation*}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
     {
        core-dist_ {\epsilon,MinPts} (o,p)  =\begin{cases} UNDEFINED & if  | N_\epsilon(P)  <  MinPts \\MinPts-th  smallest\  distance \  in\  N_\epsilon(P) & otherwise \end{cases}        
     }
\end{equation*}

    \item Reachability distance: 

\begin{equation*}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
     {
        reachability-dis_ {\epsilon,MinPts} (o,p) \\ =\begin{cases} UNDEFINED & if  | N_\epsilon(P)  <  MinPts \\max(core-dist_{\epsilon,MinPts(p)}, dist (p,o))  & otherwise \end{cases}       
     }
\end{equation*}

\end{enumerate}
```

But the problem is that the item is overflowing. Besides, I am having this error: `Missing $ inserted` and `overflow \hbox`.

Here is the picture for better understanding:

[image]

Can somebody please help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: If you have an error (such as "Missing $ inserted"), lesser information such as warnings and bad boxes is generally useless.  Once you fix the error, the other stuff may or may not go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to put these long textual expressions inside math equations. You can choose sensible variable names for any quantity you want to express mathematically. The other easy option is to put long textual expressions inside text and leave math-mode for math variables. Here I choose the second approach.

Also pay attention to how text parts are inserted into math-mode, for textual expressions use `\text` command, and for abbreviated text variables use `\mathrm`. Finally `dcases*` from `mathtools` is very useful in setting the right column to text-mode automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Core distance (core-dist$_{\epsilon,\mathrm{MinPts}}(o,p)$): A point P is a core point if it has at least minimum points within its \(\epsilon\)-neighborhood \(N_ \epsilon \)(p) (including the point P). This is defined as

    $\begin{dcases*} \mathrm{UNDEFINED} & if $N_\epsilon(P) < \mathrm{MinPts}$\\ 
    \mathrm{MinPts}-\text{the smallest distance in } N_\epsilon(P) & otherwise \end{dcases*}$.     
    \item Reachability distance (reachability-dis$_{\epsilon,\mathrm{MinPts}}(o,p)$): This is defined as
    
    $\begin{dcases*} \text{UNDEFINED} & if $N_\epsilon(P) < \mathrm{MinPts}$ \\
    \max(\text{core-dist}_{\epsilon,\mathrm{MinPts}}(p), \mathrm{dist}(p,o)) & otherwise \end{dcases*}$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @AboAmmar